# Symfony2 i18n: Is there a way to use the country code instead of the language in the route?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, localization, internationalization

Working on an app in Symfony 2 and looking at internationalisation/localisation. The default behaviour for routing is to use the language which works fine for i18n but not really for l10n.

i.e. The content for the US site will be different from the UK content but the route would be /en.

We could use /en_GB in the route, but it would be nicer if we could use /gb (or better yet, /uk)

Is there a way of doing this that doesn't involve inventing our own way of handling locales?